# How can I dynamically set the best timer interval?

Tags: .net, timer

I know I always find great answers here, so I have a new challenging question. At least for me it is really challenging.

This is the scenario: I have some jobs (let's say a lot of them). Some of them should be executed at a small number of seconds interval and some of them at intervals that can be hours. I have these jobs in a list.

Now, I use a timer in order to schedule them. But let's say I have 4 jobs:

- job1 - every 5 seconds
- job2 - every 8 seconds
- job3 - every 23 seconds
- job4 - every 10 hours.

Now, I should set the timer to at most 5 seconds so that it can execute job1 as specified. But job2 that has 8 seconds will be executed every 10 seconds. Of course... I could choose something like 2 seconds... but now... job4 will be checked every time the timer elapses the interval and this is causing performance leak (as I said I have a lot of these jobs so a big list).

So I was thinking that maybe I could use multiple timers and group the jobs dinamically considering their execution interval into some buckets of jobs... that sounds like the best option...I just need a smart idea on how to this.

That's my problem... any advice?

Comment: you need to mark some of your questions as answered (if they provided you with an answer) in order for you to continue getting great answers on here

Comment: I'd use tasks from System.Threading.Tasks each with its own timer object (.NET has more kind of timer, here I'd use System.Threading.Timer).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a single timer that only checks the need for a job to be started and give that timer an interval of a second. All it does is check and if the job should be started: pass the job to a thread or thread pool to be executed.

You might be loosing some performance due to superfluous checking and if the list of jobs is long and intervals are quite large you might switch to a different setup: set a timer for when the next job has to be started and after passing the job to a thread(pool) calculate the interval until the next job should start and adjust/set the timer. When you do this, keep in mind that you will have to check if the timer needs adjustment when you add/remove/update jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea originally: run a single timer and keep track of the elapsed interval(s) for each of your events. Creating only a single timer is preferred over multiple timers.

The concerns you raise in your question don't really matter when you're talking about a difference of between 1 to 5 seconds. The Windows timers simply don't have that precise a resolution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just a few jobs, you can use a simple `List<Job>` that contains the job's next run time. Have a timer tick once per second, check the list for jobs that need to run, and run them. When the job finishes, it updates its next run time.

If you have many jobs, create a priority queue that orders the jobs by next run time. Your once-per-second tick can then check just the first item on the queue. If it needs to run, dequeue it, start it running, and check the next item on the queue. Using a priority queue will reduce the amount of work your once-per-second timer has to do. Of course, you'll need notification when the job is done so that the handler can update the next run time and re-queue the job.